# Trying to understand how to create a jar file that opens terminal and takes in a argument

Tags: java, jar, arguments

I finished creating a program but I was told that my program
must be a Java application that takes as a command line argument the name of the file."
I understand I can use the jar command in terminal but I don't undestand how you open the terminal and take a file name as a argument. I was wondering if someone could explain what code is required to do this.
Thanks alot.

I tried creating a basic jar file in terminal with the line "jar cvf findOptimalTransport.jar ." but the jar file does not open, I think its because the current implementation takes the users input with a scannar in the code and prints via the terminal. However, this wont work because a terminal window is not opened with this command.

Comment: Hi Aidan, if my solution answers your question, please also consider upvoting! Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't have to be a **jar** file. Command line arguments can be entered from the command line, when you run your application.

Let me give you an example, about how this works. Let's say you have the below simple Java application:

```
public class MyApplication{

    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

That `public static void main()` is a method; and more specifically the main method of your application which is what is executed when compiled and ran.

To compile and then run it, you type in the command line/terminal:

```
javac MyApplication.java  //this will compile it
java MyApplication  //this will run the main method of MyApplication
```

But what is that parameter in the main method? What is `String[] arguments` ?

When you run your program, whatever you type after the application name is an **argument**, of type **String** and it is stored in the String array `String[] arguments` *(or most commonly `String[] args`)*.

What this means, is that, if you execute your application like this:

```
java MyApplication some_file.txt // Run application with one arg.
```

You can access that argument like so:

```
public class MyApplication{

    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        System.out.println("You entered: " + arguments[0]);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Hello World!
>
> You entered: some_file.txt

---

*Note: To run a jar file, you need to **navigate** to the folder that the jar file is in and from the command line you can run it by typing:*

*`java -jar <jarname>.jar`*